# How do I say "I've got all his albums"?

Tags: translation

When talking about my favorite singer, how do I say "I've got all his albums"?
I thought it was "他的光盘我都有" but I don't think it's correct because I can't find any results for that on Google.

Comment: One translation would be: 我有他所有的唱片。

Comment: in a more digital world, 专辑 might be a better translation for "album"

Comment: 专辑 is much broader and includes other kind of media collections. 唱片 is a record, no matter what the medium.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

光盘 = Disk =

So that's a huge no-no.

唱片 is more of a old fashion way of saying album. So I personally recommend 专辑.

So the result would be: 他的专辑我都有。or 我有他所有的专辑。

Answer (score 1):

Another way to say it is : 他所有的专辑我都有。
:D

Answer (score -1):

我集全了他的（所有）专辑。

或者说，
他的（所有）专辑我都集齐了。